# How to avoid Order by using temporary,filesort

Tags: mysql

What index do i need to create to avoid order by using temporary, filesort

```
  EXPLAIN SELECT   tid, sum(count)    
              FROM test  
                 WHERE cid = 1
                 GROUP BY tid
                 ORDER BY sum(count) DESC

   1    SIMPLE  test    ref     PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE,cid   cid     4   const   2   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Create table :

```
   CREATE TABLE test(
           cid INT,
           tid INT,
            datedm INT,
           count INT,
            PRIMARY KEY(cid,tid,datedm),
           INDEX(cid,tid,count),
           UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE(cid,tid,datedm)
          );
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can't: the ORDER BY is on an aggregated value which can't be indexed as such.

Note your last index is identical to the primary key. However, if you reverse it to `tid, cid`  it may help because GROUP BY implies an ORDER BY too. But, you may then have issues with the WHERE clause because of how MySQL works